# Get sequential rows that have same column values is SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to know the sequential rows which have some same values

[image]

I need the rows which have `prsstatus` value of 0 and then next row is 1

Comment: Does "next" mean in order of `TblID` values?  May we see what you've tried?

Comment: no I mean the next row in index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method, change MyTable to whatever your table is and change the `ORDER BY` clause to whatever columns you want to sort by.

```
;WITH  MyTableSort AS (
    SELECT TblID, EmpID, PrsDay, PrsTime, PrsStatus, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyTable.TblID) [Row] FROM MyTable
)
SELECT * FROM MyTableSort AS MyTableSortA 
WHERE (MyTableSortA.PrsStatus = 0 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTableSort WHERE MyTableSort.[Row] = MyTableSortA.[row]+1 AND MyTableSort.PrsStatus = 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "next" row in terms of dense values on `TblID`:

```
select YTN.*
from YourTableName as YTN inner join
   YourTableName as NR on NR.TblID = YTN.TblId + 1 and
     NR.PrsStatus = 1 and YTN.PrsStatus = 0
```

Comment: change [where] to [on] so the query can run